# Worth-it to optimize image file size for a website?

Tags: image, png, gif, bmp, optimization

I found a program called png optimizer that reduces the size of png, gif, bmp, or tga files without changing the appearance of the image at all. I was testing it out by downloading a web-page and then optimizing all the images on that page and seeing what the size difference was. If you look at the properties window for each image, optimized and not, some images are reduced in "size", but the "size on disk" remains the same.

If you want more information on "Size" vs "Size on Disk" then look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470787/please-help-me-understand-size-vs-size-on-disk.

I'm wondering if the difference between the "Size" and "Size on Disk" properties make any difference for how much data is transferred over the internet when a web-page is viewed. Basically, is it worth-it to reduce the "size" of an image for viewing over the internet if the "size on disk" remains the same?

http://www.pngoptimizer.com/

Comment: I don't understand the difference between "size" and "size on disk". Lossless optimization should make the output png smaller in bytes and have no effect on appearance (which includes dimensions) as you said, and the purpose is so that the user ultimately gets to download a smaller file.

Comment: @AlexGuerra If you open up the properties window for a file, then you will see a property called "Size" and another property called "Size on Disk", both should have a different value. From what I understand this is because of the way the OS allocates space for a file. For more information look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470787/please-help-me-understand-size-vs-size-on-disk

Comment: Then the answer is yes methinks, Size is what matters.

Comment: The "size on disk" may be the same, but consider: 1. transmitting the image over an internet connection will be faster ("the internet" does not have a "size on disk" problem), and 2. copying, loading, and displaying the file locally may go faster.

Comment: @AlexGuerra & Jongware Thanks for the answers. I just wasn't sure exactly how files are broken up into packets to be transmitted over the internet. Whether the packets include the "extra space" from the "size on disk" or not, but I guess it makes sense that they wouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically, is it worth-it to reduce the "size" of an image for viewing
>   over the internet if the "size on disk" remains the same?

Yes. The "size on disk" is only relevant for evaluating disk occupancy. To measure how many bytes are transmitted to the wire, the size-on-disk is totally irrelevant, what matters is the real size. So, any reduction in real size attained by a PNG optimizer counts here.